# Snowflake: If a value is greater or lesser than the values in an array

Tags: arrays

I need to generate a column that evaluates, if the value 3 is greater than any of the array values in an array [0,1,2,3,4] and return either true or false. Similarly i can apply lesser than or combine both conditions.

- Ive read about ARRAY_EXCEPT, ARRAY_INTERSECTION, ARRAYS_OVERLAP but they are not what i am looking for since they use the equal (=) as an operator.
- i know i could do a work around using lateral flatten but i was looking for another solution apart from expanding the arrays.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.